# How to restrict user in AzureDevops only to read Repository

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

We use AzureDevops to manage our small organization. We have few projects there and few members. Our source code is stored in TFVC(team foundation version control). Currently using Default Active Directory(Azure) to manage our small internal team.

Now, we have to give readonly access to an external user to our source code(repository). This user should not have any access to organization specific information or any project access to boards, pipelines, wiki,  etc.
We've created a new AAD user and tried to restrict it is much as possible. We tried with MS-hotmail account as external user added to the organization/project. But we cannot achieve what we want.
Also We read a lot of documentation but still cannot restrict the user in that way.

1) On project level we created a Group with full restriction on board, pipelines, analytics, etc. (image1)

2) On specific repository node we chosen some folders and gave only read access to these folders. (image2)

Any suggestions how to achieve our goal if it is even possible?

Regards,
Boris

(image 1)
[image]
(image 2)
[image]

Comment: Hi @Boris Todorov Did you check out below answer to create a new organization for your external user? how did it go with this case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this on an existing project by configuring the organization or project permission settings for this specific user.

**However, there is a workaround**. You can create a new organization and a new project without any other sensitive information, and add the external user to this organization instead of your original organization, then only move the repository from your original organization to this new organization.

In above way, you can keep the external user from viewing your organization specific information or boards, pipelines, wiki, etc.

You can also try [suggesting a feature for this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click Suggest a feature and choose Azure devops) to Microsoft Development Team. From my point of view, the source code is the core of a project much more valuable and sensitive than boards and pipelines. If a user have access to your source code, he pretty much has equivalent access to the pipelines and boards. Microsoft Development would probably cannot see the necessary to implement it.